# javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: The system does not support the specified format

Tags: java, heroku, javasound

I'm exploring the sound recording API. This is working fine on my local machine, but as soon I deployed the same on Heroku, the following line is throwing an exception:

```
 if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
        throw new LineUnavailableException(
                "The system does not support the specified format.");
 }
```

The format of the file is .wav. Is it the unavailability of a sound card on Heroku or am I missing something else?

Here is the code snippet I'm trying to execute on Heroku:

```
    format = getAudioFormat();
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

    // checks if system supports the data line
    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
        throw new LineUnavailableException(
                "The system does not support the specified format.");
    }

    audioLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);

    audioLine.open(format);
    audioLine.start();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    recordBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning) {
        bytesRead = audioLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        recordBytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Heroku does not support sound.
To find out for sure:

```
Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
for (Mixer.Info[] info : mixerInfos) {
    System.out.println("Supported: " + info);
}
if (mixerInfos.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Audio mixers are not supported.");
}
```

From the Javadocs of `getMixerInfo()`:

> Obtains an array of mixer info objects that represents the set of audio
>   mixers that are currently installed on the system.

Comment: This is not working, you are right heroku doesn't support sound, they don't have soundcard pre-installed. Let me try on aws or some other cloud vendor

Comment: your answer is correct, i mean to say heroku or for that matter any server machine doesn't have sound card support out of the box. Thank you

Comment: If the answer is correct, please accept it. Thanks!